# Can't read Task properties in Lightning controller

Tags: lightning-aura-components

How can I read a task object properties in a lightning controller.
Because var a=component.get("v.Task").Status; returns error which is Uncaught

> Error in $A.getCallback() [Cannot read property 'Status' of null].

Can anyone tells me if the Task object is supported by Lightning UI?
Thank you
this is my .cmp

```
<aura:component controller="JSMUserInfoService" implements="force:lightningQuickActionWithoutHeader,force:hasRecordId" access="global">
  <aura:attribute name="user" type="JSMUserInfo" />
    <div style="height: 6rem;">
        <div role="status" class="slds-spinner slds-spinner_large slds-spinner_brand">
            <span class="slds-assistive-text">Loading</span>
            <div class="slds-spinner__dot-a"></div>
            <div class="slds-spinner__dot-b"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="Id" />
    <aura:attribute name="Task" type="Object"/>
    <force:recordData aura:id="recordLoader"
                      layoutType="FULL"
                      recordId="{!v.recordId}"
                      targetFields="{!v.Task}"
                      recordUpdated="{!c.doInit}"
    />

</aura:component>
```

And this is my controller:

```
({
  doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
    var getProfileInfo = component.get("c.getProfileInfo"); 

     getProfileInfo.setCallback(this, function(response) {
          var state = response.getState();
         alert(state);
      if(state == "SUCCESS" && component.isValid()){
        console.log("success");   
          alert('a');
          var result = response.getReturnValue();
        console.log(result);
          var a=component.get("v.Task").Status;
          alert(a);
        if(a!= "Ouvert" ||( result.Name != "System Administrator" && result.Name != "Administrateur système")){
          alert("aaaaa");
        } else {
          var CreateTask = component.get('c.CreateTask'); 
          CreateTask.setCallback(this, function(response){
          var state = response.getState(); // get the response state
          if(state == 'SUCCESS') {
            var res = response.getReturnValue();
            res.Id = component.get("v.Task").Id;
            var getUserInfo = component.get('c.getUserInfo'); 
            getUserInfo.setCallback(this, function(response){
              var state = response.getState();
              if(state == 'SUCCESS') {
                var info = response.getReturnValue();
                res.OwnerId = info.Id;
                var updateTask = component.get('c.updateTask');
                updateTask.setParams({
                  "task" : res
                });
                updateTask.setCallback(this, function(response){
                  var state = response.getState();
                  if(state == 'SUCCESS') {
                    window.location.reload();
                  }
                });
                $A.enqueueAction(updateTask);
              }
            });
            $A.enqueueAction(getUserInfo);
          }

          });
          $A.enqueueAction(CreateTask); 
        }
      }else{
          console.error("failresponse.getError()[0].message"); 
      }        
   });
  $A.enqueueAction(getProfileInfo);  
}
})
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add more context. There are specific Lightning components that do not support Task.

Comment: I edited my post, thank you David Reed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<force:recordData>` does not support Task and Event.

The [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/force:recordData/documentation) on the component refers us to the UI API documentation for a list of supported objects. That list is [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.uiapi.meta/uiapi/ui_api_get_started_supported_objects.htm). Task and Event aren't listed and are unsupported.

This is in common with other base Lightning components, like [`<lightning:recordViewForm>`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:recordViewForm/documentation), where it's explicitly stated that

> This component doesn't support all Salesforce standard objects. For example, the Event and Task objects are not supported.

You'll have to use Apex to access these records, unfortunately.

Comment: how  to use Apex to access these records?

Comment: @SFtrainer Making a call to server-side Apex is documented in the Lightning Developer Guide: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/controllers_server_actions_call.htm